# Primes $p=n^6+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, irreducible-polynomials, computational-mathematics

Which is the least odd prime $p=n^6+1$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$? I have tested for $n\leq 10,000$ without finding any.

Due to a conjecture of Bunyakovsky there are an infinite number of such primes, since $X^6+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: How is your question related to `irreducible-polynomials`?

Comment: Certainty now, $X^6+1$ is $not$ irreducible...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If $n>1$ $$n^6+1 = \underbrace{(n^2+1)}_{>1}\underbrace{(n^4-n^2+1)}_{>1}$$   then $p$ is not a prime.

Comment: Nice answer, with it due to $n^6 + 1 = \left(n^2\right)^3 + 1$.